# Retrieve Twitter tweets in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, twitter

this is my first time using Twitter API therefore I am not very familiar. I want to retrieve all twitter tweets which has a hashtag, for example #converse

This is my code:

```
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=converse"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void{ 
    var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXML.status[0].text);

    load1.text = myXML.status[0].text;
}
```

This is the error I got :

> Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=converse
>       at mainClass()

I don't understand the URL and I don't know if the syntax is correct. I searched in the internet and this is how they retrieve the feeds.

Comment: Try adding a listener for that error and trace whatever info you can get from it.

Comment: FOr sure you are not listening to all events you should listen. As Grapefrukt says check more why this happens. Also it may be easy to use an existing API. How about https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#flash

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply! I managed to display tweets with this url http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=SMCSConverse but I want to retrieve tweets with a specified hashtag. But the resources online are making me confused. Thanks for your help!

Comment: First thing I would do is to add listeners for the `HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS`, `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` and `SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR` events. These will give you more insight into what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

change the URL you are using for this other:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=pcinfo72

Comment: That url is going to give the users' timeline instead of public timeline. The OP wants to search all tweets for a specific hashtag.

Comment: Outdated: The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.